# Filter ps output by CPU time

Tags: linux, bash, awk

Not sure if this belongs here or at Linux and Unix.

I am running the following command...:

```
ps -eo pid -eo pcpu -eo pmem -eo time -eo command | sort -k 2 -r | awk '/frmweb/ && !/PID/ && $2+0>0' > /tmp/deadpidlist.log
```

to get a nice list like this:

```
7445  3.4  0.3 00:00:06 frmweb webfile=HTTP-0,bosscars_prod_jpi
7570  2.2  0.2 00:00:01 frmweb webfile=HTTP-0,prod_sso
7550  1.3  0.2 00:00:01 frmweb webfile=HTTP-0,prod_sso
24730  0.8  0.3 00:01:55 frmweb webfile=HTTP-0,prod_sso
7557  0.8  0.2 00:00:00 frmweb webfile=HTTP-0,prod_sso
16893  0.6  0.2 00:02:19 frmweb webfile=HTTP-0,prod_sso
20906  0.5  0.2 00:01:40 frmweb webfile=HTTP-0,prod_sso
```

This was fine for a while, but my script likes to pick up processes that have just spawned. So what I would like to do is filter this list even further by only considering PIDS with more than a minute of CPU time (column 4).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
... | awk '/frmweb/ && !/PID/ && $2+0>0 && substr($4,4,2)+0>1'
```

The `substr` function allows you to grab 2 characters from the 4th column starting at position 4 (and the two after that) to test against `>1` condition. If it is true, the line will get printed.

Or, as suggested by [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25732291/filter-ps-output-by-cpu-time/25732886?noredirect=1#comment40232369_25732886) in the comments:

```
... | awk '/frmweb/ && !/PID/ && $2+0>0 && $4!~"00:00:"'
```

Comment: Or simpler, `$4 !~ '00:00:'`.

Answer (score 1):

Just let the `ps` to do the sorting.

```
ps kcputime -o pid,cputime,comm
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you want to an arbitrary amount of time:

```
#!/bin/bash

SECONDS_THRESHOLD=60

while read pid pcpu pmem time command; do
    days="0"
    # in case of days, 01-00:00:00
    if [[ $time =~ /-/ ]]; then
        IFS=':-' read days hours minutes seconds <<< $time
    else
        IFS=':' read hours minutes seconds <<< $time
    fi
    totalSeconds=$( echo "$days * 86400 + $hours * 3600 + $minutes * 60 + $seconds" | bc )   
    if [[ $totalSeconds -gt $SECONDS_THRESHOLD ]]; then
        echo $pid $pcpu $pmem $time $command
    fi
done < <(ps -eo pid -eo pcpu -eo pmem -eo time -eo command | sort -k 2 -r | awk '/frmweb/ && !/PID/ && $2+0>0') > /tmp/deadpidlist.log
```